# Data Annotation error message is not displaying in postman response

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

i have web api 3.0 solution and i dont have any UI for that.All my response i have cheking in postman only .
**For input validation** i have used data annotation but i couldnt see the error message in post man.please help me what mistake i have done.

currently i am getting the error message like:

```
{
"studentid": [
"Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'studentid', line 2, position 26."
 ]
 }
```

but i want to display the error message like:

```
    student Id is required.This cannot be null or blank


    //[Required (ErrorMessage = "student Id is required.This cannot be null or blank")]
     //public int StudentId { get; set; }
```

What i have done so far:

1. my model

   ```
   public class Employee
   {
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "student Id is required.This cannot be null or blank")]
     public int StudentId { get; set; }
     [Required (ErrorMessage = "Student name is required.This cannot be null or blank")]
      [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
       public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Student age is required.This cannot be null or blank")]
         public int Age{ get; set; }
           }
   ```
2. my controller

   ```
      [HttpPost("api/Student/Check")]
       public async Task Check([FromBody] students input)
       {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
       returnBadRequest(Modelstate);
          }
        else {
       returnOk();
       }
        }
   ```
3. created one class for ValidatorActionFilter.cs

   ```
    public class ValidatorActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
      public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
      if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
         {
         filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(filterContext.ModelState);
         }
         }
            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
           {
           }
            }
   ```

startup.cs

```
              public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
           {
          services.AddMvc(options =>
          {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidatorActionFilter));
           });
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in postman which you are getting is correct.

By default `int` datatype is not `nullable`, so if you assign `null` to `int` then you will get error.
Your API is working as expected, no one should pass `null` or `string` to `int` datatype, but if you want your `StudentId` to take `null` then make it `nullable`, like this:

```
public class Employee
    {
      [Required (ErrorMessage = "student Id is required.This cannot be null or blank")]
      public int? StudentId { get; set; }
      //rest of your properties
    }
```

Comment: okay ..suppose i need to give a validation for more model which is not in model class but in response .any possibility? response coming from different api

Comment: you will only get response from the api which you have called, so there is no possibly at all of response coming from different api.